# How to ensure video is played from website, not a cached version

Tags: c#

I have used the below code(read a video from a website and play it on a panel) its working, but this video is stored on my computer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
namespace webplayer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int width = panel1.Width;
                int height = panel1.Height;
              System.Uri u = new Uri("http://cassfordinfo.com/Testmovie.avi");                Video video;
              video = Video.FromUrl(u);

                video.Owner = panel1;
                video.Stop();
                video.Play();

                // resize the video to the size original size of the panel

                panel1.Size = new Size(width, height);
            }catch(Exception gh)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(gh.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Once I run the exe it will read from the website but I have unplugged the internet connection and run it.  It runs the same video without a connection. I have restarted my computer and again if I run the exe file I can view the video.

Whenever I need to run this program it should read it from my website not from temporary file.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think this is a programming question.  You're asking us how to find a file on your computer

Comment: I would imagine it's probably somewhere in your temporary internet files

Comment: Open Windows explorer - do 'Find' and search for '*.avi' created today.

Depending on whether you've got indexing switched on and how large your hard drive is this might take a while.

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: If the goal is to modify the program so that it doesn't use a cached version, then it could be interpretted as a programming question.

Comment: @forsvarir - yes I agree; however the question text is 'please help me find the temp video file stored on my computer'.

The question should be rewritten as 'how do I stop this Video class from caching?' with information about the Video class

Comment: no i have searched for the file in my computer but i cant.i need not to play the video without sync with the website

Comment: @forsvarir - I'd +1 you for the edit if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to take a look at media streaming.  This can be done in a variety of ways - some would suggest silverlight though, as I understand it, it can be done through asp.Net using [Windows Media Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448620.aspx).

It could also be done from other project types in different ways, but it looks like you need it for ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have voted to close (I am also a bit grumpy today), here's my two cents anyway:

I assume you're using the [Video Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms902629.aspx) from DirectX and so therefore the first question has to be whether you have any control over caching.

Judging by the API you can't - you just get to pass it a Uri and that's it.

Therefore I have a couple of questions:

- Have you tried playing a video that has changed between the last play?  Does the app correctly use the new version instead of the old cached version?  If it does, then there's presumably no problem when a user's 'net connection is good.
- Why must it always play the most recent version?  Is it actually because if the 'net connection is down you want to make sure the user doesn't see a video?  If that's the case try manually issuing an HTTP HEAD request to the video url using `HttpWebRequest`, or (because HEAD isn't always supported by web servers) the old trick of pinging well-known ping-friendly domain names or, even better, firing a web request at your own website - if the net connection is down you don't even try to play the video.

Finally, I guess you're after the file so you can try and delete it.  My guess is that this is going to be almost nigh-on impossible to track at runtime - the file probably doesn't even have the .avi extension and is likely to be random.

Your best bet to find it on a single run, however, is to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to monitor your machine for file activity whilst your app connects to the video and plays it for a few seconds.  Assuming the file is being accessed directly by the app (and not indirectly via some service or other exe that Dx shells) you should be able to filter the captured events down to just your app and you will see lots of file activity.